# Getting this error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Contract: id value of incorrect type

Tags: apex, trigger

I got this error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Contract: id value of incorrect type when using update trigger. I have researched online for similar issues, but none if them helps. Is there anything wrong with "Contract__c= ur.Contract__c" in the last part of my code?

```
trigger trgr_createSunkUserRevenueRecord on Account (before update) {

List<id>conRevId = new List<id>();
List<Sunk_User_Revenue__c>sunkUserRevenues = new List<Sunk_User_Revenue__c>();
List<Revenue__c>conRev = new List<Revenue__c>();
List<Revenue_Source__c>rs = new List<Revenue_Source__c>();

    for (account a:trigger.new)
    {           
            conRev = [select id from Revenue__c where contract__r.account__c =:a.id];
            createSURList();

    }

    insert (sunkUserRevenues);

    List<Sunk_User_Revenue__c> createSURList()
    {       
        for (integer i = 0; i < conRev.size(); i++)
        {   
            conRevId.add(conRev[i].id);
        }

        for (user_revenue__c ur:[select Contract__c, revenue__c, Date_Paid__c, Revenue_Amount__c, Revenue_Earned_By_User__c, Revenue_Split_Percentage__c, user__c from user_revenue__c where Revenue__c in: conRevId]) 
        {
            sunkUserRevenues.add(createRecordFromConRev(ur));
            delete ur;
        }

        return sunkUserRevenues;
    }


    Sunk_User_Revenue__c createRecordFromConRev (user_revenue__c ur)
    {

        Sunk_User_Revenue__c r = new Sunk_User_Revenue__c (Contract__c= ur.Contract__c, Revenue__c = ur.Revenue__c, Date_Paid__c = ur.Date_Paid__c, 
        Revenue_Ex_GST_Amount__c = ur.Revenue_Amount__c, Revenue_Ex_GST_Earned_By_User__c = ur.Revenue_Earned_By_User__c, Revenue_Ex_GST_Split_Percentage__c = ur.Revenue_Split_Percentage__c, User__c = ur.user__c);      

        return r;
    }


}
```

Comment: Just a hunch but did you accidentally make the lookup a "Contact" lookup instead of a "Contract" lookup? Been there...

Comment: Can you tell the relation between Sunk_User_Revenue__c, Contract__c, and Account

Comment: The Id which you are using to Contract__c field is not compatible. Please check the field was created properly with the Contract Object. Also, your code needs to be modified as there are chances that would hit the governor limit.

Comment: I've just checked and there is no "Contact" lookup.
Sunk_User_Revenue__c has a lookup field of contract__c, contract object has a lookup field of account__c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code in the first for loop so that there is no error message now. However, nothing happens when I update the account. The trigger should create some Sunk_User_Revenue__c records but actually not.

```
trigger trgr_createSunkUserRevenueRecord on Account (before update) {

List<id>conRevId = new List<id>();
List<Sunk_User_Revenue__c>sunkUserRevenues = new List<Sunk_User_Revenue__c>();
List<Revenue__c>conRev = new List<Revenue__c>();
List<Revenue_Source__c>rs = new List<Revenue_Source__c>();

    for (account a:trigger.new)
    {           
        List<contract>accContract = [select id from contract where accountId =: a.id];
        set<id>accContractId = (new Map<Id,contract >(accContract)).keySet();
        conRev = [select id from Revenue__c where contract__c in: accContractId];
        createSURList();

    }

    insert (sunkUserRevenues);

    List<Sunk_User_Revenue__c> createSURList()
    {       
        for (integer i = 0; i < conRev.size(); i++)
        {   
            conRevId.add(conRev[i].id);
        }

        for (user_revenue__c ur:[select Contract__c, revenue__c, Date_Paid__c, Revenue_Amount__c, Revenue_Earned_By_User__c, Revenue_Split_Percentage__c, user__c from user_revenue__c where Revenue__c in: conRevId]) 
        {
            sunkUserRevenues.add(createRecordFromConRev(ur));
            delete ur;
        }

        return sunkUserRevenues;
    }


    Sunk_User_Revenue__c createRecordFromConRev (user_revenue__c ur)
    {

        Sunk_User_Revenue__c r = new Sunk_User_Revenue__c (Contract__c= ur.Contract__c, Revenue__c = ur.Revenue__c, Date_Paid__c = ur.Date_Paid__c, 
        Revenue_Ex_GST_Amount__c = ur.Revenue_Amount__c, Revenue_Ex_GST_Earned_By_User__c = ur.Revenue_Earned_By_User__c, Revenue_Ex_GST_Split_Percentage__c = ur.Revenue_Split_Percentage__c, User__c = ur.user__c);      

        return r;
    }


}
```

Comment: It's working now.